# How to unregister onclose event handler in JavaScript SignalR client

Tags: javascript, react-native, signalr, signalr.client

User logs into application and it starts a connection and registers a handler to restart `SignalR` connection if it is lost like this

`connection.onclose(this.restartConnection);`

I've looked through `HubConnection.ts` and I did not find any option to remove `onclose` handler. It cannot be replaced by an empty method because it stores all registered methods. Then there is only option to remove custom handlers through

`connection.off('methodName');`

When a user logs out the application stops `SignalR` connection at it inevitably fires the `onclose` handler which ends up with an error for me. I want to unregister the handler so the connection will not try to restart itself after the application deliberately stopped it.

I thought of using a flag if it should or should not try to restart the connection but that does not seem right to me. Is there a proper solution to this?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?  I'm having same issue in a React app, where after the user logs out, I'm trying to unload signalr and unbind the onclose auto-reconnect code.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest version of the SignalR client (which still doesn't seem to have a documented way to do this) you can just set the `onclose` callbacks array to empty yourself: `connection._closedCallbacks = []`.